# How to align HTML DATA right or left using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a HTML table from JSON data and formatted that JSON in java script as i a HTML table i have required.

The place where i am stuck is i want to right align all the amount coming ffrom my JSON data.
All the numbers i want to align right only but not able to do that

here is my javascript code with json

```
var data = [
            {
                "amount": 476426,
                "billdate": "2018-09-01",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 92141,
                "billdate": "2018-09-01",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 115313,
                "billdate": "2018-09-01",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 511153,
                "billdate": "2018-09-02",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 115704,
                "billdate": "2018-09-02",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 83597,
                "billdate": "2018-09-02",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 167421,
                "billdate": "2018-09-03",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 53775,
                "billdate": "2018-09-03",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 269711,
                "billdate": "2018-09-04",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 58849,
                "billdate": "2018-09-04",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 82998,
                "billdate": "2018-09-04",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 335833,
                "billdate": "2018-09-05",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 66177,
                "billdate": "2018-09-05",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 85396,
                "billdate": "2018-09-05",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 259445,
                "billdate": "2018-09-06",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 61144,
                "billdate": "2018-09-06",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 61782,
                "billdate": "2018-09-06",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 294481,
                "billdate": "2018-09-07",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 61872,
                "billdate": "2018-09-07",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 66403,
                "billdate": "2018-09-07",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 451206,
                "billdate": "2018-09-08",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 111289,
                "billdate": "2018-09-08",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 96784,
                "billdate": "2018-09-08",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 578767,
                "billdate": "2018-09-09",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 124466,
                "billdate": "2018-09-09",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 97088,
                "billdate": "2018-09-09",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 181344,
                "billdate": "2018-09-10",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 27940,
                "billdate": "2018-09-10",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              }
            ];

                     let formatData = function (data) {

                         let billdates = [];
                         let outlets = [];
                         data.forEach(element => {
                             if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
                                 billdates.push(element.billdate);
                             }
                             if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
                                 outlets.push(element.outlet);
                             }
                         });
                         return {
                             data: data,
                             billdates: billdates,
                             outlets: outlets
                         };
                     };

                     let renderTable = function (data) {
                         billdates = data.billdates;
                         outlets = data.outlets;
                         data = data.data;
                         let tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
                         let table = document.createElement("table");
                         let thead = document.createElement("thead");
                         let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
                         let th = document.createElement("th");
                         th.innerHTML = "Bill_Date";
                         headerRow.appendChild(th);
                         let grandTotal = 0;
                         let outletWiseTotal = {};
                         outlets.forEach(element => {
                             th = document.createElement("th");
                             th.innerHTML = element;
                             headerRow.appendChild(th);
                             outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
                             data.forEach(el => {
                                 if (el.outlet == element) {
                                     outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
                                 }
                             });
                             grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element];
                         });
                         th = document.createElement("th");
                         th.innerHTML = "Total";
                         headerRow.appendChild(th);
                         thead.appendChild(headerRow);
                         headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
                         th = document.createElement("th");
                         th.innerHTML = "Total";
                         headerRow.appendChild(th);

                         outlets.forEach(element => {
                             th = document.createElement("th");
                             th.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element];
                             headerRow.appendChild(th);
                         });
                         th = document.createElement("th");
                         th.innerHTML = grandTotal;
                         headerRow.appendChild(th);
                         thead.appendChild(headerRow);
                         table.appendChild(thead);

                         let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

                         billdates.forEach(element => {
                             let row = document.createElement("tr");
                             td = document.createElement("td");
                             td.innerHTML = element;
                             row.appendChild(td);
                             let total = 0;
                             outlets.forEach(outlet => {
                                 let el = 0;
                                 data.forEach(d => {
                                     if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
                                         total += parseInt(d.amount);
                                         el = d.amount;
                                     }
                                 });
                                 td = document.createElement("td");
                                 td.innerHTML = el;
                                 row.appendChild(td);
                             });
                             td = document.createElement("td");
                             td.innerHTML = total;
                             row.appendChild(td);
                             tbody.appendChild(row);
                         });

                         table.appendChild(tbody);

                         tbl.innerHTML = "";
                         tbl.appendChild(table);
                         table.classList.add("table");
                         table.classList.add("table-bordered");
                     };
                     let formatedData = formatData(data);
                     renderTable(formatedData);
```

I dont know how can i achive that and there is a TOTAL at last also i want to make that  so that it can be bold.

except date i want all the numbers to be right align[here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/6ndfu18e/)

Comment: `.table TD {text-align: right;}` in the stylesheet should do the trick.

Comment: *"i want to right align all the amount"* What have you tried so far and what do you mean by *"the amount"*? Could you update your question to include your attempt(s) and be more specific, thank you.

Comment: @NewToJS  Grandtotal,outletwisetotal,hourwise total these are my amounts

Comment: @dheerajkumar and what have you tried so far? Please update your question and include your attempt(s). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try usign bootstap class **text-right** or **text-center** to **th** and **td**

```js
var data = [
             {
                 "amount": 476426,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-01",
                 "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 92141,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-01",
                 "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 115313,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-01",
                 "outlet": "KOLAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 511153,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-02",
                 "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 115704,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-02",
                 "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 83597,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-02",
                 "outlet": "KOLAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 167421,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-03",
                 "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 53775,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-03",
                 "outlet": "KOLAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 269711,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-04",
                 "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 58849,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-04",
                 "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 82998,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-04",
                 "outlet": "KOLAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 335833,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-05",
                 "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 66177,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-05",
                 "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 85396,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-05",
                 "outlet": "KOLAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 259445,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-06",
                 "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 61144,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-06",
                 "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 61782,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-06",
                 "outlet": "KOLAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 294481,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-07",
                 "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 61872,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-07",
                 "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 66403,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-07",
                 "outlet": "KOLAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 451206,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-08",
                 "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 111289,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-08",
                 "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 96784,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-08",
                 "outlet": "KOLAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 578767,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-09",
                 "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 124466,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-09",
                 "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 97088,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-09",
                 "outlet": "KOLAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 181344,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-10",
                 "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
               },
               {
                 "amount": 27940,
                 "billdate": "2018-09-10",
                 "outlet": "KOLAR"
               }
             ];

                      let formatData = function (data) {

                          let billdates = [];
                          let outlets = [];
                          data.forEach(element => {
                              if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
                                  billdates.push(element.billdate);
                              }
                              if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
                                  outlets.push(element.outlet);
                              }
                          });
                          return {
                              data: data,
                              billdates: billdates,
                              outlets: outlets
                          };
                      };

                      let renderTable = function (data) {
                          billdates = data.billdates;
                          outlets = data.outlets;
                          data = data.data;
                          let tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
                          let table = document.createElement("table");
                          let thead = document.createElement("thead");
                          let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
                          let th = document.createElement("th");
                            th.classList.add("text-center");
                          th.innerHTML = "Bill_Date";
                          headerRow.appendChild(th);
                          let grandTotal = 0;
                          let outletWiseTotal = {};
                          outlets.forEach(element => {
                              th = document.createElement("th");
                              th.innerHTML = element;
                              headerRow.appendChild(th);
                              outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
                              data.forEach(el => {
                                  if (el.outlet == element) {
                                      outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
                                  }
                              });
                              grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element];
                          });
                          th = document.createElement("th");
                           
                            
                          th.innerHTML = "Total";
                          headerRow.appendChild(th);
                          thead.appendChild(headerRow);
                          headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
                          th = document.createElement("th");
                           th.classList.add("text-center");
                          th.innerHTML = "Total";
                          headerRow.appendChild(th);

                          outlets.forEach(element => {
                              th = document.createElement("th");
                               th.classList.add("text-center");
                              th.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element];
                              headerRow.appendChild(th);
                          });
                          th = document.createElement("th");
                           th.classList.add("text-center");
                          th.innerHTML = grandTotal;
                          headerRow.appendChild(th);
                          thead.appendChild(headerRow);
                          table.appendChild(thead);

                          let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

                          billdates.forEach(element => {
                              let row = document.createElement("tr");
                              td = document.createElement("td");                           
                            
                              td.innerHTML = element;
                              row.appendChild(td);
                              let total = 0;
                              outlets.forEach(outlet => {
                                  let el = 0;
                                  data.forEach(d => {
                                      if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
                                          total += parseInt(d.amount);
                                          el = d.amount;
                                      }
                                  });
                                  td = document.createElement("td");
                                   td.classList.add("text-right");
                                  td.innerHTML = el;
                                  row.appendChild(td);
                              });
                              td = document.createElement("td");
                               td.classList.add("text-right");
                              td.innerHTML = total;
                              row.appendChild(td);
                              tbody.appendChild(row);
                          });

                          table.appendChild(tbody);

                          tbl.innerHTML = "";
                          tbl.appendChild(table);
                          table.classList.add("table");
                          table.classList.add("table-bordered"); 
                           table.classList.add("text-center");
                           
                      };
                      let formatedData = formatData(data);
                      renderTable(formatedData);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="tbl"></div>
```